# What does the `var: expression` syntax do in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

After searching for the reason of a `NameError` in my script for way too long, I realized that I mistyped `=` as `:` on the related assignment, i.e.:

```
In [1]: a: 1
In [2]: # ...
In [3]: a += 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3a23b85b51e9> in <module>()
----> 1 a += 1
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

What I find curious about this is that the syntax `var: expression` neither seems to do anything nor throws an error.
This appears to work in IPython or a local console for **python 3**
In python 2 the syntax gives an error!

Any hints as to what happens here?

Comment: It's a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: It *might* be a type hint, which is just one use case for a *variable annotation*, which is what this is.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into this! But why does type hinting work with literals? Is that syntax equivalent to `a: int`?

Comment: @mrclng Python itself doesn't care *what* that annotation is, as long as it is a valid Python expression. External tools like `mypy` are what *interpret* the value as a type for type checking.

Comment: (It's somewhat unfortunate that an annotation alone can suppress the `NameError` you would have gotten from `a` alone, but I think it's the result of the *intention* that the annotation be used as a type hint.)

Comment: Hmm I see... So should I close this question or keep it so people that come across the same issue as I did can find it?